# Type error while looping through array in PL/pgSQL

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, foreach, plpgsql

I am a beginner with PostgreSQL. Trying to loop here the values that I pass:

`companyregistration` just calling the `companyRegistrationValidator`

The function call:

```
SELECT companyregistration(
'876786576544', 
'TraderAnalytics',
'TraderAnalytics@gmail.com,
'@kjvfhjh88976',
ARRAY['86578657865','Natali','Vladimirov','Natali.Vladimirov1990@gmail.com', '+@jvfhjh88976'],
ARRAY [['Maks','Burkov'],['Yan','Burkov']],
'Netherlands',
'Company');
```

> ```
> [2018-10-28 18:29:15] [42804] ERROR: FOREACH expression must yield an array, not type text
> [2018-10-28 18:29:15] Where: PL/pgSQL function companyregistrationvalidator(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,text[],text[],character varying) line 28 at FOREACH over array
> ```

The function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION companyRegistrationValidator (company_id VARCHAR, comp_name VARCHAR, comp_email VARCHAR, comp_password VARCHAR, employees text[], creators text[], country VARCHAR)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE
    checked BOOLEAN := FALSE ;
    r_id VARCHAR; r_name VARCHAR; r_email VARCHAR; r_password VARCHAR; r_country VARCHAR;
    cr_counter INTEGER = 0; em_counter INTEGER = 0; c_ar_length INTEGER  = 0; e_ar_length INTEGER = 0;
    ar_index text; creator text; val text;

BEGIN
    SELECT id_r , email_r , password_r , country_r , firstname_r INTO r_id , r_email , r_password, r_country , r_name FROM regex;

    c_ar_length := cardinality(creators);
    e_ar_length := cardinality(employees);

    FOREACH val IN ARRAY employees LOOP
        IF val ~ r_id THEN em_counter := +1;
        ELSEIF val ~ r_name THEN  em_counter := +1;
        ELSEIF val ~ r_email THEN em_counter := +1;
        ELSEIF val ~ r_password THEN em_counter := +1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    FOREACH creator IN ARRAY creators LOOP
        FOREACH ar_index IN ARRAY creator LOOP
            IF ar_index ~ r_name THEN cr_counter := +1;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    IF cr_counter = c_ar_length AND em_counter = e_ar_length AND company_id ~ r_id AND comp_name ~ r_name AND comp_email ~ r_email AND comp_password ~ r_password AND country ~ r_country
        THEN checked := TRUE;
    END IF;

    RETURN checked;
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What's the error in my code?

Comment: Oh I see. I had a similar issue not too long ago. It's when you're iterating through the array of arrays in a nested FOREACH. That won't work. The first FOREACH already has unnested everything in a single "level", so it yields text, not arrays, so you can't do another FOREACH on its results. Can't remember off the top of my head how I got around it.

Comment: If you can give me answer with code example it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This nested loop construct is good for the error you quote:

```
    FOREACH creator IN ARRAY creators LOOP
        FOREACH ar_index IN ARRAY creator LOOP
            IF ar_index ~ r_name THEN cr_counter := +1;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
```

The loop variable `creator` in the outer loop is defined as type `text`, which is fine. But you cannot nest another loop through `creator` like you try - nor do you need to.
[The manual on *Looping Through Arrays*:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)

> The elements are visited in storage order, regardless of the number of array dimensions.

So, to loop through all base elements, *regardless of array dimensions*, all you need is:

```
    FOREACH creator IN ARRAY creators LOOP
       IF creator ~ r_name THEN cr_counter := cr_counter + 1;
       END IF;
    END LOOP;
```

Also note that `cr_counter := +1` would not increment `cr_counter` like you seem to be trying. Would just assign `1` repeatedly. I replaced it with the expression to actually increment.

**However**, like so often, unless the array is trivially tiny, a **set-based approach** will be (much) faster. Like:

```
    SELECT INTO cr_counter
           count(*) FILTER (WHERE _creator ~ r_name)::int
    FROM   unnest(creators) _creator;
```

(And are you sure you want the regexp operator `~` there?)

Comment: Thanks for the full answer i appreciate it i will test your examples ..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  FOREACH expression must yield an array, not type character varying

When I tried to iterate an array with a [FOREACH statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp VARCHAR;
  arr VARCHAR := ARRAY['a','b','c','d'];
BEGIN
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

So, I set `[]` just after `VARCHAR` as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp VARCHAR;
  arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY['a','b','c','d'];
BEGIN     -- ↑↑ Here
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, I could iterate the array with the [FOREACH statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) as shown below:

```
INFO:  a
INFO:  b
INFO:  c
INFO:  d
DO
```

In addition, I set `SLICE 0` with `temp` of array type (`VARCHAR[]`) as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE -- ↓ Here
  temp VARCHAR[];
  arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY['a','b','c','d'];
BEGIN       -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, I got the error below:

> ERROR:  FOREACH loop variable must not be of an array type

And, I set `SLICE 1` with `temp` of non-array type (`VARCHAR`) as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE -- ↓ Here
  temp VARCHAR;
  arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY['a','b','c','d'];
BEGIN       -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
  FOREACH temp SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, I got the error below:

> ERROR:  FOREACH ... SLICE loop variable must be of an array type